# Invalid index at line 22 of function horner in Scilab

Tags: scilab

I'm using Scilab 5.5.2, and the function 'horner' for evaluating polynomials is not working at all.

I wonder how I can fix it?

Thanks!

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aijra.png)

Comment: if you could share your code directly on the post the community might be more keen on helping you

Answer (score 0):

I just checked your code and it works ...

What Scilab version do you use?
Check if you have  defined a new version of the horner function or if you import an external module which contains the definition of an other horner function....